# how to handle exception in aria2c in python

Tags: python

I m new to Python. I am trying to download a file using aria2c, but I am not sure how to handle the exception in the event my download fails. Can anyone help me on this?

Attached Code:

```
def sample():
value = "aria2c  -x 10 -k 1M -s 10 --http-user=%s --http-passwd='%s' %s" %(username, password, url)
      print value
      try:
          r=os.system(value)
```

I want to capture it and send it as an email.
Can anyone with prior experience help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with aria2c, but you may take a look into this:
https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#exit-status

Answer (score 0):

From the `aria2c` docs linked by ProtectedMethod and the `os.system` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), it seems all you need is a bunch of `if`s (assuming you're running this in a standard shell on a modern operating system).

```
r = os.system(value)

if r == 0:
    handle_success()
elif r == 1:
    handle_unknown_error()
elif r == 2:
    handle_timeout()
# etc
```

Another way would be to define a mapping of error codes to handlers:

```
handlers = {
    0: handle_success,
    1: handle_unknown_error,
    2: handle_timeout,
    # etc
}

r = os.system(value)
handlers[r]()
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thanks for your response. It was very helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Go ahead and accept the answer if it solves your question :)